# Pumping lemma for non regular languages

Tags: pumping-lemma

I read that pumping lemma is sufficient condition to prove non regularity of languages but **not** necessary condition.

I know the first part that it is sufficient is true but not able to understand why is it not necessary. Can someone please help me with this statement?

Comment: If the condition is not necessary then there must be some other way to prove language is non regular right ? Can you tell me what is that way ?

Comment: We have a reference question for that: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular.

Comment: Thanks Yuval . I got my answer from that reference question. I marked it as duplicate.